# How Can I Set Margin with 'dp' programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create design with programmatically. I'm using LayoutParams for details and I want to set Margin and I saw ...**setMargins(0, 100, 0, 100)** But I want to set with 'dp' like this:

```
<TextView
          ...
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          .../>
```

How can set margin with 'dp' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you got to know the parent layout first if it's RelativeLayout you'll need:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(this);
```

and if it is Linear,Make sure you replace Relative with Linear to get the right layoutParams.Now you can use:

```
layoutParams.setMargins(i1,i2,i3,i4);
```

all the values should be in pixel so if you need a method,it should convert dp to px for you.Feel free to use mine then:

```
public int dpToPx(Context context, float dp) {
    return Math.round(dp * getDisplayMetrics(context).density);
}
```

now just set the layoutParams to the child view:

```
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Thank you but the TextView in the LinearLayout. So can I use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams in the LinearLayout? or I must to use RelativeLayout?

Comment: You're welcome.No each layout has its on just use:
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this);

Comment: Thanks again, I will try now :)

Comment: @FatalError Please Upvote as well if it helped you :)